# Verifying progress reported from an async call is properly report in unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, mvvm, moq

I'm working on some code that can automatically detect the serial port that a device (in this case, a spectrometer) is connected to.

I have the auto detection piece working, and I'm trying to write tests for the ViewModel that shows the progress of detection, errors, etc.

Here's the interface to the code that does the actual detection.

```
public interface IAutoDetector
{
  Task DetectSpectrometerAsync(IProgress<int> progress);
  bool IsConnected { get; set; }
  string SelectedSerialPort { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the ViewModel that uses the `IAutoDetector` to detect the spectrometer

```
public class AutoDetectViewModel : Screen
{
   private IAutoDetector autoDetect;
   private int autoDetectionProgress;

   public int AutoDetectionProgress
   {
      get { return autoDetectionProgress; }
      private set
      {
         autoDetectionProgress = value;
         NotifyOfPropertyChange();
      }
   }

   [ImportingConstructor]
   public AutoDetectViewModel(IAutoDetector autoDetect)
   {
      this.autoDetect = autoDetect;
   }

   public async Task AutoDetectSpectrometer()
   {
      Progress<int> progressReporter = new Progress<int>(ProgressReported);
      await autoDetect.DetectSpectrometerAsync(progressReporter);
   }

   private void ProgressReported(int progress)
   {
      AutoDetectionProgress = progress;
   }
}
```

I'm trying to write a test that verifies progress reported from the `IAutoDetector` updates the `AutoDetectionProgress` property in the `AutoDetectionViewModel`.

Here's my current (non-working) test:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task DetectingSpectrometerUpdatesTheProgress()
{
   Mock<IAutoDetector> autoDetectMock = new Mock<IAutoDetector>();
   AutoDetectViewModel viewModel = new AutoDetectViewModel(autoDetectMock.Object);

   IProgress<int> progressReporter = null;
   autoDetectMock.Setup(s => s.DetectSpectrometerAsync(It.IsAny<IProgress<int>>()))
      .Callback((prog) => { progressReporter = prog; });

   await viewModel.AutoDetectSpectrometer();
   progressReporter.Report(10);
   Assert.AreEqual(10, viewModel.AutoDetectionProgress);
}
```

What I want to do is grab the `IProgress<T>` that is passed to `autoDetect.DetectSpectrometerAsync(progressReporter)`, tell the `IProgress<T>` to report a progress of 10, then make sure the `AutoDetectionProgress` in the `viewModel` is 10 as well.

However, there's 2 problems with this code:

1. It does not compile.  The `autoDetectMock.Setup` line has an error: `Error  1   Delegate 'System.Action' does not take 1 arguments`.  I've used the same technique in other (non-synchronous) tests to gain access to passed values.
2. Will this approach even work?  If my understanding of async is correct, the call `await viewModel.AutoDetectSpectrometer();` will wait for the call to finish before calling `progressReporter.Report(10);`, which won't have any effect because the `AutoDetectSpectrometer()` call has returned already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the return type for the callback; the compiler will not be able to determine this for you.

```
autoDetectMock
      .Setup(s => s.DetectSpectrometerAsync(It.IsAny<IProgress<int>>()))
      .Callback((prog) => { progressReporter = prog; }); // what you have
```

should be

```
autoDetectMock
      .Setup(s => s.DetectSpectrometerAsync(It.IsAny<IProgress<int>>()))
      .Callback<IProgress<int>>((prog) => { progressReporter = prog; });
```

You also aren't returning a Task from your Setup, so that will fail as well.  You'd need to return a Task.

I believe, after you fix these two things, it should work.