# How to unit-test the progress report of an async call?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, .net-4.0, nunit-3.0

### Goal

I want to test the progress reporting of some async call which accepts a IProgress.
I want to verify:

- if this reported progress is always within the range of [0.0; 1.0]
- has increasing values (last value <= next value)
- reports 1.0 at some point, eg as last call

I want to use as few frameworks as possible -> a solution without using another 3. party library would be nice.

### Problem/My trys

I tryed to write a simple async Task test methode to the achive this. I call the methode to test with await eg. `await asyncCallToTest(new Progress((p) => { Assert.someting(p); }))`. And maybe use stack variables in the lambda. Full examples later.

This however resulted in Tests that succseed even if it should not be possible or sometimes a test passed and then it failed without changes....

### Code

I have recreated the issues with a simple stand alone test class:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using NUnit.Framework;

namespace FastProgressReporter
{
    public class Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public async Task SampleOkTest()
        {
            await TestReporter(new Progress<double>((p) => {
                Assert.GreaterOrEqual(p, 0);
                Assert.LessOrEqual(p, 1);
            }));
            //Sometimes fails, sometims passes. Why?
        }

        [Test]
        public async Task SampleFailTest()
        {
            await TestReporter(new Progress<double>((p) => {
                Assert.GreaterOrEqual(p, 2); // Has to Fail, however passes.
                Assert.LessOrEqual(p, 3);
            }));
        }

        [Test]
        public async Task ReportsIncremental()
        {
            double latestProgress = 0;
            await TestReporter(new Progress<double>((p) => {
                p = 1 - p; //Force Decrement...
                Assert.GreaterOrEqual(latestProgress, p); //Should fail on second call
                latestProgress = p;
            }));
        }

        [Test]
        public async Task ReportsOneOneOrMoreTimes()
        {
            double maxProgress = 0;
            await TestReporter(new Progress<double>((p) => {
                maxProgress = p > maxProgress ? p : maxProgress;
            }));
            Assert.AreEqual(0, maxProgress); //Should always fail
            //Sometimes fails, sometims passes. Why?
        }

        // Methode under test
        public static async Task TestReporter(IProgress<double> progress)
        {
            progress.Report(0);
            await Task.Run(() => { /*Do nothing, however await*/ });
            progress.Report(0.5);
            await Task.Run(() => { /*Do nothing, however await*/ });
            progress.Report(1);
        }
    }
}
```

### Envoriment

VisualStudio 2019, .net-framework 4.7.2, NUnit3 test project

### Quesiton

How do I achive my goals reliable and correctly?

### Releated Questions

[Verifying progress reported from an async call is properly report in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320444/verifying-progress-reported-from-an-async-call-is-properly-report-in-unit-tests) This uses a 3 party libary which I am trying to avoid and has the .Report() call inside of the test methode directly, not in the async mehoed called by the test

Thank you for your help.

Comment: ty, fixed @Fildor

Comment: I'd try this: Have `Progress` append all values to a list. Then make your assertions on the list. (Should be "sorted", Shouldn't be empty, Should have X items, First item should be A, Last Item should be B ... )

Comment: And I'd use `await Task.Delay(someMillis);` instead of `await Task.Run( () => { /* Nothing really */ });`

Comment: Either use Task.Delay or Task.Yield instead of Task.Run. It's not a big change, but these methods are better suited for what you want to achieve with Task.Run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Soluion

As suggested by @Andrei15193, I tryed to implement IProgress by my self to get rid of the Progress class.

```cs
private class UnitTestProgress<T> : IProgress<T>
{
    private Action<T> handler;

    public UnitTestProgress(Action<T> handler)
    {
        this.hander = handler?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hander));
    }

    public void Report(T value)
    {
        handler(value);
    }
}
```

I have chosen a very simple class here as an implmentation.

As far as I have tested, if Progress is replaced by my new class the problems are solved and the unittests are reliable.

Answer (score 2):

You can add all progress reports to a list then do the asserts on the collection. The number of items will be equal to the number of progress reports and in the same order. You can check any number of conditions related to progress report.

About your tests failing, this is odd because if they ran correctly then they should have the same result each time you ran them because there is no dependency on state. The only dependency is on the test runner actually running async tests. NUnit should be able to do that, as far as I know it has support for async tests.

The Progress instance captures the current SynchronizationContext and runs the callback using it. This is particularly useful for UI because the progress callback will be executed on the UI thread so you don't need to worry about that. It is likely that NUnit has its own custom SynchronizationContext for executing async tests and your tests sometimes failing and sometimes not may be related to progress reports being executed after the related test has actually finished. In this case, you may actually get the assert exception of one test on a different test.

If this is true, then you may need to have your own implementation of IProgress that does not use the SynchronizationContext in order to properly have the progress reports executed. Basically what you want is to have your callback executed when you call the report method. Your implementation can do exactly that, whenever you call the progress method it will add the reported value to a list, that is exposed through a property, and then do the asserts using the property.

What is giving you your strange results is most likely the usage of the Progress class as it internally depends on the SynchronizationContext to execute the callback.

Comment: Ok, I teste it with a adding the reported progress to a list and than assert -> still random and incorrect results

```
[Test]
public async Task SampleFailTest()
{
    List<double> reportedData = new List<double>();
    await TestReporter(new Progress<double>((p) => {
        reportedData.Add(p);
    }));
    foreach (var e in reportedData)
    {
        Assert.GreaterOrEqual(2, e); // Has to Fail, however still may pass.
        Assert.LessOrEqual(-1, e);
    }
}
```

and yes might be the Progress class itself

Comment: @ProfBits it is most likely the Progress instance. Try with a custom IProgress implementation, it's only one method.